# Deployed WildFly WebSocket Giving poor Performance in Openshift . Need to restart the application in Openshift Site

Tags: java, websocket, openshift

Deployed **WildFly Websocket** application **OPENSHIFT** . Everything was going good . But Sometime Websocket is not working properly. Then again Everytime i am logging in **Openshift Site**  and **Restarting the application**. After that it's working fine. After sometime again websocket is not working . Please help me to solve this. How to keep the application always live in OPENSHIFT  ??

Answer (score 3):

You might try checking for Memory Limit Violations (https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399600-How-to-check-for-memory-limit-violations).  If you are using small gears you might be running out of memory, your application may require a medium or large gear to work properly.  Especially if you are running WildFly + a database on the same gear.  Also keep in mind that the JVM is allocated 1/2 of the available gear memory by default, you can read more about that here (https://developers.openshift.com/en/wildfly-jvm-memory.html)

Comment: Thanks moleculartear. I have planned to create a Forum in Android Application . So I used **WildFly + MySQL database** in server side with **websocket** Code .I am new to Openshift. So What do you suggest me to get always my server code active without any interrupt ??